# Warn when I'm commenting that the answer has been deleted

Tags: feature-request, comments

Currently if an answer is deleted while you're writing a comment on it, you don't get notified until you press Enter to submit the comment. I find that very jarring, especially due to the bright red color. It's also annoying to get it after spending the better part of a minute writing a clear comment.

It would be nice if we could get an orange bar saying that the answer has been deleted while we're writing the comment, instead of the red popup when submitting it.